# How to find the value $\frac {1}{1001}$+$\frac {1}{1002}$+$ \frac {1}{1003}$. . . . $\frac {1}{3001}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the value of $X$?

If $X$= $\frac {1}{1001}$+$\frac {1}{1002}$+$
\frac {1}{1003}$. . . . $\frac {1}{3001}$

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, $x=\frac1{1001}+\frac1{1002}+\cdots+\frac1{3001}$ is the unique (real) solution.

Comment: $\int_1000^3001 \frac{dx}{x} =\log\frac{3001}{1000}$ is not a bad approximation.

Comment: Ignoring barto's facetious comment: There is no simple formula for this. You just have to do the arithmetic. (But there are very good approximations available.)

Comment: And DavidH really meant $\int_{1000}^{3001} \frac{dx}{x} =\log\frac{3001}{1000}$.

Comment: @TonyK Argh, thanks for catching that. Clumsy me

Comment: @DavidH: And in fact $\int_{1000.5}^{3001.5} \frac{dx}{x} =\log 3$ is a better approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How to find the value of X ?*

You don't. All you can do is to approximate it with $\ln3000-\ln1000=\ln\dfrac{3000}{1000}=\ln3$.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wolfram Alpha, the exact answer is $\frac{p}{q}$, where 
p=75328031318485390324661526737425033504382783697307257420576924210199013865675494588453357597732611836759615279262897804228616138318504937188371116285762401242413015264220245625479603089419098916457166245209822607501071955143499155953588750190801459033569902371944986875832208531524214828639697643189965117705382654989852370599753740878627879853483787696654677713060906781015657974936128342382392285649376707442839841179748088751298833747872798844076570494507780225749022929010768355428164437169302405535535364154990753024705481864063860017478507389655897233586797811430528294182048959446223923598196249442135891217435883947315129246902187725246250598067420776140788952327658325678502701284402300815156540371036195063003627486059021552907734502862589610721915821193440593974954781712319953123170734301914497590285511175026077731937589721512275001092521417536559660349265700268430040798622819564401017864757739795100181374338527553865490907433079559312179804056893247878014980769034106784211416486427494110137143167726890741012450902524382016709863255621914636546018196139306200607120112035754193101797513239991492135601146320147050994872715861596583104447145670782396748805189295043563824059380013910741630415788589094785297982336752288051949876466345284300334533818775485735929036146857606273476737333144687
and
q=68566531279903628912686455689707762035187218980388472531818931221958143227040137485566325964619669558509920485829503840213156491378105416097859140787570909163265838858706060495340080601871261988532528073722857103208163591171453249496963221949000399595906940217890999758063758045600496397218639237756801379116714936907189264418517317848373281952463530695109614931068018579566062545346842001231262506076974738267939850559454231717656259370454715943739489846432220408266436405743383253335947738008816316420815936026338093013782076698663690993643987282074025771028584395877711978236168705319634952035546058102196465266094685597850839130112444421743346563438994002058641939513027378913267407309287523130290409441356981921372056659086236100173594357097198287699815700073687104112287650768268409060993927723692727795317967782792493532735160560983640097780774026793902802329162609514356813613404373046193497169872443197790118543274296291015758965419813085403237331785330094743458034277833761189510285871016868053278321608864897615096982508710403676706674326523034795706489260558438180338079964279882266757471688021586869860522419765557336317312645948642787671563307725326223661077615937980880502844240344055840043277923862912310720505496149062384179496213136193385018508630698975487803093967780513084297517697280000.

You're not going to find a nicer way to express the exact answer in closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica gives an approximation of

1.098612251

Ref.: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427egmfbkbu8jv&mail=1

Just to note that $\ln 3 \approx 1.098612288$.  So the approximation given before are VERY good...

Answer (score 0):

The exact answer is $$\begin{align}
H_{3001}-H_{1000}&=(\gamma+\psi_0(3002))-(\gamma+\psi_0(1001))\\ \,\\&=\dfrac{\Gamma'(3002)\Gamma(1001)-\Gamma'(1001)\Gamma(3002)}{\Gamma(1001)\Gamma(3002)}\\\,\,\\
&\approx 1.09861225...
\end{align}$$ where $H_n$ is the $n$-th Harmonic number defined as: $$H_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1k$$ which can be expressed analytically by the formula: $H_n=\gamma+\psi_0(n+1)$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi_0$ is the Digamma function defined as: $$\psi_0(n):=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dn}\ln \big(\Gamma (n)\big)=\dfrac{\Gamma'(n)}{\Gamma(n)}$$ where $\Gamma(n)$ is the gamma function which is equal to $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$.

Comment: This may well be correct, but is it helpful?

Comment: @TonyK In what context? Since if the question seeks to find an exact *closed form* to that sum then my answer is perfect. If it just wants an approximation then the answers above already gave it.

Comment: In the sense that if I want the exact value, then I won't get it from your formula.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, you can [get it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\dfrac{\Gamma%27%283002%29\Gamma%281001%29-\Gamma%27%281001%29\Gamma%283002%29}{\Gamma%281001%29\Gamma%283002%29}) from that formula.

Comment: It says "Decimal approximation". That's not an exact value.

Comment: @TonyK What is your definition of an exact value?

Comment: See pi37's answer.

Comment: @TonyK I see now what you mean. Thanks.